# Adding magnificPopup via Fluid

Tags: typo3, typoscript, magnific-popup

I want to add images via a DCE in Typo3. For normal images you just have to add a tick to activate jh_magificpopup for images. But within the DCE, I cant just check a box or something to add the magnificpopup. so I looked into the Source-code and found that magnificpopup adds a class named "magnificpopup to the a-tag of the images. So i tried it this way:

```
<f:section name="main">
<div class="row">       
<f:for each="{dce:fal(field:'images', contentObject:contentObject)}" as="fileReference" iteration="iterator">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> 
        <a class="magnificPopup" href="fileadmin/user_upload/{fileReference.originalFile.name}">
            <f:image src="{fileReference.uid}" alt="" treatIdAsReference="1" width="200px"/>    
        </a>
    </div>
</f:for>
</div>
```

But this does not work. Any Idea what im Doing wrong? It is opening the picture in a new tab, bus just in fileview. But there should be the lightbox that should be openend on the same site.

Comment: Is the class output in the frontend? Also check if there are no js errors

Comment: No js errors there. The class is visable in the source code of the frontend, but it does not work. the js of magnificpopup is also added automatically by the plugin. jh_magnificpopup. Its working for other pictures on the page which are not part of the DCE.

Comment: Can you post the link to the non-working page?

Comment: Nope, its local. But I managed to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it like this. It was missing a class thats needed.

```
<f:section name="main">
<div class="row">
<f:for each="{dce:fal(field:'images', contentObject:contentObject)}" as="fileReference" iteration="iterator">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> 
        <div class="image-wrap csc-textpic-imagewrap">
        <a class="magnificpopup" href="fileadmin/user_upload/{fileReference.originalFile.name}">
            <f:image src="{fileReference.uid}" alt="" treatIdAsReference="1" width="200px"/>    
        </a>
        </div>  
    </div>
</f:for>
</div>
```

Missing classes were `class="image-wrap csc-textpic-imagewrap"`